# exclude search pattern with select-string in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using select string to search a file for errors. Is it possible to exclude search patterns as with grep. Ex:

```
grep ERR* | grep -v "ERR-10"

select-string -path logerror.txt -pattern "ERR"
```

logerror.txt

```
OK
ERR-10
OK
OK
ERR-20
OK
OK
ERR-10
ERR-00
```

I want to get all the ERR lines, but not the ERR-00 and ERR-10

Comment: do you have a single ERR item per line?

Comment: Use `-Exclude 'ERR-10'`

Comment: I don't have a ERR per line

Comment: -(not)match should work, you might wanna have a look at the help and/or post a sample of your file

Comment: @Hitesh The -Exclude is for the -Path only, not the pattern

Comment: `(Get-Content logerror.txt | Select-String -Pattern "ERR") -NotMatch "ERR-10" -NotMatch "ERR-00"`. You can elaborate this simple-minded approach appreciating that [`-NotMatch` operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847759.aspx) accepts [regular expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315294.aspx).

Comment: @JosefZ - Thank you for your answer. It works if I only have 1 -NotMatch operator ...if I have more then 1, it doesn't work

Comment: `$($($(Get-Content $logError) -Match "ERR") -NotMatch "ERR-10") -NotMatch "ERR-00"` or even `(((Get-Content $logError) -Match "ERR") -NotMatch "ERR-10") -NotMatch "ERR-00"` for more comparison operators.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you can use `Where-Object` here.

```
Write-Output @"
OK
ERR-10
OK
OK
ERR-20
OK
OK
ERR-10
ERR-00
"@ > "C:\temp\log.txt"

# Option 1.
Get-Content "C:\temp\log.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -Match "ERR*"} | Where-Object { $_ -NotMatch "ERR-[01]0"}

# Option 2.
Get-Content "C:\temp\log.txt" | Where-Object { $_ -Match "ERR*" -and $_ -NotMatch "ERR-[01]0"}
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I understand what you want to do, but this is just an example. If I have more and more complex error codes (like I do), this doesn't work: Example:ERR-201,ERR-422;ERR-240. I just needed a way to filter the erros, because some are really erros and others are just informations.

Comment: @PedroSales, You modify the regexp then. The code I've shown is the equivalent of `grep -v "ERR-[01]0"`, i.e. you use a regexp to exclude lines from the output. I guess you already know how to emulate `grep` without the `-v` argument.

Comment: With grep, I just pipe another grep -v with another error code

Comment: Exactly. Ok, I will modify my answer to match your combination of greps.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I've een around with this for a couple of days now.

Answer (score 34):

I use "-NotMatch" parameter for this

```
PS C:\>Get-Content .\some.txt
1
2
3
4
5
PS C:\>Get-Content .\some.txt | Select-String -Pattern "3" -NotMatch    
1
2
4
5
```

For your case the answer is:

```
Get-Content .\logerror.txt | Select-String -Pattern "ERR*" | Select-String -Pattern "ERR-[01]0" -NotMatch
```